# ClickOnce deployment fails on "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0 Version 8.0.0.0" missing from GAC althought it's not used in the project?

Tags: c#, iis-7, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, gac

We are publishing a WinForm application based on the .NET 4 framework towards IIS7 via ClickOnce. Once the end-user starts installing the application from the link provided we get following error:[image]

Why is .NET asking for this assembly? The project is build in VS2013, why would it use an assembly from VS2010? Does anyone know what this is about? On the machine all the latest updates are installed for the .Net Framework.

Is there a way to remove unused references from the project perhaps?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your references and remove if the above Assembly is referenced. if you still need it do a Copy Local on that reference property.

Also right click on your project and go to properties: and under publish tab. click on application files and click show all files. and if the above assembly is listed there select exclude if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The 2nd option worked perfect for me. I excluded all that was not needed. The application installed and worked fine after I published it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to remove any unused references from the project.